# Showing the pending migration when im trying to switch to another branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> im doing this one

rake db:migrate

> but still im getting this error
>
> You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake
>   10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

instead. Or uninstall the newer version of rake, if you do not need it in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try running following command.

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, your system has loaded a different version of rake than the one listed in your app's Gemfile.lock, so rake is aborted. Check your Gemfile.lock for rake version.

When you run something with bundle exec, it ensures that only the gem
versions in your Gemfile.lock are specified.

Check out [but-i-dont-want-to-bundle-exec](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/but-i-dont-want-to-bundle-exec) article for detailed information.